# Iptables stuck in D state all the time and causing server load

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, openvz

I am running iptables/csf on a centos 5.11 openvz vps.
I can't start/stop/flush iptables/csf.

Further looking into it I could see the csf is waiting for iptables. And iptables is stuck as you can see below.

This is the result of `cat /proc/29745/stack` :

```
[<ffffffff814b01f9>] xt_compat_lock+0x29/0x30 
[<ffffffffa051b171>] compat_do_replace+0x181/0xad0 [ip_tables] 
[<ffffffffa051bd1f>] compat_do_ipt_set_ctl+0x7f/0xc0 [ip_tables]
[<ffffffff814af867>] compat_nf_sockopt+0x67/0xe0 
[<ffffffff814af921>] compat_nf_setsockopt+0x21/0x30 
[<ffffffff814c17da>] compat_ip_setsockopt+0xaa/0xc0 
[<ffffffff814e1d15>] compat_raw_setsockopt+0x25/0x70 
[<ffffffff8146a08c>] compat_sock_common_setsockopt+0x1c/0x30 
[<ffffffff8149e209>] compat_sys_setsockopt+0x69/0x210 
[<ffffffff8149e4a5>] compat_sys_socketcall+0xf5/0x210 
[<ffffffff81058b40>] sysenter_dispatch+0x7/0x2e 
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

iptables is stuck at the sys call `#define __NR_socketcall      102` which in turn is stuck at `xt_compat_lock`.

I am not sure what exactly the call is. Could someone please shed light on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Although the `uptime` command et.al. will show a load of 1, no CPU activity is actually connected to that load; it just means that there is one process waiting for a system resource, in this case a (deadlocked?) lock inside netfilter or something like that. So it's not like this "load" is causing other processes to get less CPU time or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to openvz and to be sure, run this command to ensure that the correct iptables modules are installaed

`/etc/csf/csftest.pl`

Run it and give us the result.

Comment: Any command run on csf/iptables just hangs and the process goes into D state

Comment: edit the iptables configuration file and modify IPTABLES_MODULES_UNLOAD= no , the configuration file path is: /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config , then try to start/restart the iptables service